# XEP - 0055 with iOS and ejabberd?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to implement XEP-0055 which is supported by ejabbed as shown here in [supported xeps](https://www.ejabberd.im/protocols)

This is my request:

```
XMPPIQ *iq = [[XMPPIQ alloc] init];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:@"testuser1@company.com"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"company.com"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:@"search1"];
XMPPElement *query = [XMPPElement elementWithName:@"query"];
[query setXmlns:@"jabber:iq:search"];
[iq addChild:query];
[self.xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```

I am getting this response:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="company.com" to="testuser1@company.com/2834146151141475281662718" type="error" id="search1">
<query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"/>
<error code="501" type="cancel">
<feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>
</error>
</iq>
```

Why am I receiving feature-not-implemented? Link to official XEP [description.](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ejabberd, the search functionality is delegated to a subdomain, by default using the `vjud` prefix. Try sending the search request to `vjud.company.com` instead.

Comment: As I thought, the error was in "to" attribute! Now it works, thank you very much! But where can I find all possible services that ejabberd implements? I mean possible values of "service" in service.company.com?

Comment: You can get those by sending a disco items request (see XEP-0030) to the "main" server, i.e. `company.com`.

Comment: Yes,I did this several times,but I see erlang modules in the response like 'vcard-temp' or 'carbons', but these are modules. Should I treat module as a service? Also, I stack with some other problem. Can you,please, have a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26803450/error-400-bad-request-with-xep-0055)? I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you see `vcard-temp` in the result, then you probably sent an *info* request, not an *items* request.

Comment: Yes, using http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#**items** retrieves conference, pubsub and vjud .company.com.Thanks again!