# How to send iq to search "Username" instructed XEP-0055 implemented by Openfire on iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp

I'm working on an Instant Message App using XMPP. And I want to search users when adding friends to figure out if the user exists. I've read XEP-0055 on http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0055.html and I sent the iq like **Example 1. Requesting Search Fields**. Then I received the response as following:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" id="search2" from="search.127.0.0.1" to="admin@127.0.0.1/iPhone">
    <query xmlns="jabber:iq:search">
        <instructions>
            The following fields are available for searching. Wildcard (*) characters are allowed as part of the query.
        </instructions>
        <first></first>
        <last></last>
        <nick></nick>
        <email></email>
        <x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
            <title>
                Advanced User Search
            </title>
            <instructions>
                The following fields are available for searching. Wildcard (*) characters are allowed as part of the query.
            </instructions>
            <field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden">
                <value>jabber:iq:search</value>
            </field>
            <field var="search" type="text-single" label="Search">
                <required></required>
            </field>
            <field var="Username" type="boolean" label="Username">
                <value>1</value>
            </field>
            <field var="Name" type="boolean" label="Name">
                <value>1</value>
            </field>
            <field var="Email" type="boolean" label="Email">
                <value>1</value>
            </field>
        </x>
    </query>
</iq>
```

I want to search the field "Username" and I sent the iq

```
<iq type="set" to="search.127.0.0.1" id="search2" from="admin@127.0.0.1" xml:lang="en"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:search"><Username>gq</Username></query></iq>
```

but I get the error response

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="search2" from="search.127.0.0.1" to="admin@127.0.0.1/iPhone"><error code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></bad-request></error></iq>
```

And I know that it must be wrong with the iq's format. But I really don't know what format it should be. Can anyone figure it out?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800596/xep-0055-with-ios-and-ejabberd

Comment: check out more with this link https://github.com/dbsGen/XEP-0055